# LMC program do not output the correct sum

Tags: little-man-computer

```
loop    inp
        sta numa
        sub validate
endthis brp loop
        bra label1
label1  lda numa
        sub validate1
        brp label2
        brz label2
endthis bra loop
label2  lda num
loop    sta num
        add total
        sta total
        sta num
        sub one
        brp loop
        lda total
        out
validate dat 11
validate1 dat 5
numa    dat
num     dat
total   dat 
one     dat 1
```

This program will let the user to input the number between 5 to 10 and calculate the sum of the numbers from 1 to the input specified by user and print the result in the output display. For example, if the user input 5, the sum will be 15.

Comment: If you are serious about getting an answer, then please explain what the program is supposed to calculate. It currently makes no sense, since it doesn't use the input in the calculation.

Comment: No reaction? Voting to close this.

Comment: i am going to write a program which the user can only input the number between 5 to 10 and calculate the sum of the numbers from 1 to the input specified by user and print the result in the output display. For example, if the user input 5, the sum will be 15.

Comment: OK, I see what you want. Could you edit your question, and add that information? Also, will you be around to give feedback on an answer?

Comment: what information that I have to add? Sure

Comment: Just what you wrote in comments as the aim of the program. It should be in the question, not just in comments

Comment: Alright, edited

Comment: Ok great. I will prepare an answer. Stick around! 

Comment: Posted an answer. Please let me know whether this is helpful or you need clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following issues with the code:

- Some labels are not unique, like `loop`. So that means it is not clear where the execution should jump with the `brp loop` instruction. Depending on which simulator you use, you can get different behaviours. You should use unique names for the labels.
- The second part of your code -- where the calculation is done -- starts with:

  ```
  label2  lda num
  loop    sta num
  ```

  ... but that just reads and writes what is in `num`, which is useless. You really want to *copy the input* to `num`, and so this should be:

  ```
  label2  lda num2
  loop    sta num
  ```
- A bit further down the code you have this:

  ```
  sta total
  sta num
  sub one
  ```

  ...but this overwrites `num` with the total, and then subtracts one from the total. Yet, you want to subtract one from the value that is counting down from the input number, not from the total. So what you really need here is to *get* that count-down value and then subtract:

  ```
  sta total
  lda num    # corrected
  sub one
  ```
- Your program does not have a `hlt` instruction, which means execution will fall-through into the "data section" of your program. So add `hlt` here:

  ```
  lda total
  out
  hlt    # stop execution
  ```

There are also the following things to improve:

- The `endthis` label is never referenced: it is not needed.
- In this code:

  ```
  brp label2
  brz label2
  ```

  ... the `brz` instruction will never result in a jump to `label2`, because a zero is already captured by `brp`. It may be confusing, but `brp` means: "branch when not negative", so it also branches when the accumulator is zero. Therefore you can just remove that `brz label2`; it is not needed.
- The following `bra` instruction:

  ```
          bra label1
  label1  lda numa
  ```

  ... will jump to `label1` or else just proceed with that line also. So it is a useless jump. You can just take out that `bra label1` line, and remove the label also.
- A LMC can be reset to run again from the top. In that case you must take into account that the data is *not* reset, and so it is good practice to have code that initialises data to initial values at the start of your program. In this particular case, you'll want to reset the total back to 0, as otherwise you'll be adding to the total of a previous run.
- I would suggest using more meaningful names. For example, `label1` and `numa` are not really clarifying what they are used for.

Suggested solution:

```html
          lda zero   # added: initialise total
          sta total
getinput  inp
          sta input
          sub toogreat
          brp getinput
          lda input
          sub minimum
          brp inputok
          bra getinput
inputok   lda input     # corrected
loop      sta countdown
          add total
          sta total
          lda countdown # corrected
          sub one
          brp loop
          lda total
          out
          hlt   # added
toogreat  dat 11
minimum   dat 5
input     dat 4
countdown dat
total     dat 0 
zero      dat 0
one       dat 1

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.816/lmc.js"></script>
```